# "put as much effort as he could" vs "put effort as much as he could"

Tags: expressions

Is there any difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

"He put as much effort as he could into his work because he eagerly wanted to change the world with computers."

"He put effort into his work as much as he could because he eagerly wanted to change the world with computers."

Comment: 1. Words & phrases can be moved around a bit in a sentence to shift focus. 2. The two sentences do not mean exactly the same thing, there can arguably be pragmatic differences/ subjective interpretations. Grammar may not be of much help as both are grammatical.

Comment: Obviously, the 'as much' refers to 'effort' in the first instance and to 'he could' in the second. They are entirely different when viewed from this perspective.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, thus the comment, but CMIIW both sentences actually have identical meaning.

Comment: As a native speaker, I would say that the second sentence is awkward.  It's passive or something.  I wouldn't use it, even if the meaning is technically the same.  It makes "effort" sound like a concrete concept, like flour, eggs, milk and butter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that "He put as much effort as he could into his work" expresses a strong sense that the "he" in the sentence put some effort into the work under discussion, and that whatever that amount of effort proved to be, it was "as much as" he was capable of putting into it.

In contrast, "He put effort into his work as much as he could" suggests to me that he did direct some effort toward work, when he could. But this formulation leaves me with the lingering sense that he may sometimes have put his effort elsewhere altogether, even though he tried to direct it toward work as much as he could.

My impression may be purely subjective, but I think that the first wording does a much better job of commending the person who made the effort than the second wording does.

Comment: That is a very acute observation, I think. Thank you very much